# Posicionamiento div - CSS

Tags: html, css, div

Quiero que un div se me coloque en el margen superior derecha de la página pero que no descuadre el otro div que debe estar centrado en TODA la página. Es decir, un div para "saludar al usuario" arriba a la derecha, y un div "reservar" en el centro de la página.

Cuando incluyo el div de "saludar al usuario", se descoloca el de "reservar".

**¿Qué ocurre?
Código CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
    /*background: #DEDEDE;*/
    display: flex; /*Centrado en la página tanto vertical como horizontal.*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*Imagen de fondo no se vaya con el scroll de la página.*/
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}

.sesion_cliente{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}


.busqueda{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    padding: 18px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

input{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFDA63, #FFB940);
    border: 0;
    width: 160px;
    color: brown;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


.form-link{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php
//Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
session_start();
//Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
    $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
        <div class="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$cliente."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                    //Redireccionamos a la página "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" en 0 segundos.
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="busqueda">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">
                <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basta con que el div de clase "sesion_cliente" le des un posicionamiento absoluto`(position:absolute)` para que se coloque arriba a la derecha, de esta manera no solo conseguirás colocarlo en esa posición sino que además como se sale del flujo normal de la página, no podrá molestar al otro div y ese simplemente lo ignorará.

En el css la clase "sesion_cliente" quedá de la siguiente manera:

```
.sesion_cliente{

    /*Codigo añadido*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    /*---------------*/
    padding: 5px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

El resto lo dejas como estaba

Comment: Cierto. Lo he probado y funciona. Muchas gracias. El problema que tenía era que modificaba también al otro div... al ser independientes eso me fastidiaba.

Comment: De nada, un saludo!

Comment: Igual puedes echarme un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126658/colocar-div-debajo-de-otro-div-css es algo similar que me sigue dando problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias.